# Скрипт python .exe закрывается из-за ошибки

Tags: python

Компиляция прошла успешно, но при запуске скрипта вылетают ошибки и скрипт сразу закрывается
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

4 строка

```
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
```

Вообще не могу понять в чём дело

Comment: Здесь описано решение ошибки: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31233777/python-source-code-string-cannot-contain-null-bytes

Comment: @Tehnorobot не помогло